# How do I fix null is not an object React Native Splash Screen

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I have followed the instructions from this exactly: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen
As well as watching a youtube video that goes over the same steps.

My code is:

```
import * as React from 'react';    
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import HomePage from './src/Home';
import {navigationRef} from './RootNavigation';
import * as RootNavigation from './RootNavigation.js';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(1000);
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomePage}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

The app runs exactly how it should, but only web I remove the componentDidMount method. The line where I set SplashScreen.hide(); is what is causing the error.

The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeSplashScreen.default.hide')

This error is located at:
    in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:109)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:135)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

componentDidMount
    App.js:47:4
```

I have tried doing the manual installation, making sure the react-native-splash-screen is installed and running npm install, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are you using expo?

Comment: No, I am not using expo.

Comment: you can delete your setTimeout call. This will run nothing after 1s.

Comment: Will do, I’ve tried this code with/without that call, still the same error.

Comment: Did you update your `MainActivity.java` ?

Comment: Yes I updated the MainActivity.java file, I am testing this on iOS.

Comment: @giotskhada what if one *is* using Expo? Getting started with a new project and trying to move to Expo and got this error.

Sorry to thread jack :)

Answer (score 1):

After running `react-native run-ios`

I found that I was manually linking react-native-splash-screen package when the version of react-native I am using supports autolinking.

After running `react-native unlink react-native-splash-screen` and then `react-native run-ios` this fixed my issue.

Comment: My problem was similar. I didn't need to unlink, but I did need the `react-native run-ios` step to completely refresh the app on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm thinking is that you should call the SplashScreen.hide() function in the callback of your setTimeout() function. Here:

```
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(1000, () => SplashScreen.hide());
}
```

If this doesn't work, please try checking what value does the SplashScreen object hold.